# markdown can't handle tags with asterisks

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, markdown

On the main site, you can (for example) ignore tags using this notation [tag:foo*], which will ignore stuff tagged as [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) but also [foo-bar](/questions/tagged/foo-bar).

The nice markdown highlighter for tags seems to have a problem with asterisks, though -- as you can see in this post.

I would have expected them to be highlighted the *same way* as they are on the front page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want `[tag:foo*]` to get converted into a link like `[tag:foo]` is? If yes, where should it link to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a tag called [foo*]. Yes, you can wildcard-ignore several tags at once, but the `[tag:xyz]` syntax is there for linking to *one specific* tag. So it wouldn't make sense to allow asterisks in it.

Comment: It could still be *rendered* correctly, even if it doesn't link anywhere.