# Chat / markdown do not parse links or tags with an asterisk in them

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, tags, chat, hyperlinks

I use the tag `php*` as a favourite, to catch all of the badly (version specific) tagged PHP questions. When trying to link this tag in chat with `[tag:php*]` that tag is not parsed.

Also when pasting a link to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*` everything before the asterisk is converted to a link, and the asterisk itself is omitted.

Looks like the markdown parser for questions doesn't handle it for tags either.

[tag:php*]

Markdown parser does do it for links in questions, but it does not work for chat.

[test link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*)

Using the `[title](url)` format in chat also filters out the asterisk.

Comment: The behaviour for `[tag:php*]` is [intentional](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140525/markdown-cant-handle-tags-with-asterisks). The `[title](url)` issue likely just means chat needs an updated MarkdownMini parser to bring it inline with [how comments should now work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88297/url-filter-goes-rogue-on-unicode-characters-in-urls/128824#128824).

Comment: See this issue for asterisks in URLs: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/percent-encoding-of-asterisks-in-links

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/a-star-in-a-url-breaks-the-linkification-in-posts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644092/can-an-url-have-an-asterisk too

Comment: This is kind of annoying. There's an image that I physically cannot get to display in chat either inline or even just as a link because of `*` in the URL.

Comment: [It seems to work...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*)

Comment: @Sklivvz [cough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175431/my-edit-didnt-do-anything-yet-it-is-still-shown#comment606812_175431) :)

Answer (score 1):

The starred link works [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php*), in its preview, in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/chat-markdown-do-not-parse-links-or-tags-with-an-asterisk-in-them#comment706809_159551). It's broken in the [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1781140#1781140), but only on postback (not in the javascript call).

Marking as reproduced.

Comment: Year later, any update?