# My edit didn't do anything, yet it is still shown

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, revisions-list, rollbacks

[Here is the history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15845693/revisions) of a question I tried to edit.

I first clicked edit on revision 4. Then I added the [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) tag because it was correct. I then saved it.

What happened then? My edit... didn't do anything at all!

---

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZlOt.png]

---

What did I break? What happened?

## EDIT

It appears I must zoom out a bit to clear some confusion:

---

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYA78.png]

To summarize: my intent was to roll back the change made to the body text by the suggested edit while preserving the change made to the tags. While the tag change was kept, the body changes were not rolled back!

Comment: Did you make the same changes as revision 5? If so, and given the timing, it's a simple edit clash.

Comment: Yes, adding a tag *is* a radical change.  */jokingSarcasm*

Comment: @Seth No, he changed other stuff too

Comment: @Bart Please see updated post

Comment: Don't be so radical man

Comment: FWIW: I reproduced this. I'll try to elaborate on why it happens at some point, but for now the evidence is in the revision history here.

Comment: @David How does something become un-reproduced?

Comment: @Doorknob we're not using `status-reproduced` any more, since it doesn't mean anything has actually been resolved. Comments capture the "We've reproduced this" adequately enough.

Comment: @DavidFullerton looks like the dev team is not familiar with the decision to not use the [status-reproduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) tag anymore. Personally  I'm against that decision but it's your call. Anyway, think you better nuke that tag or blacklist it so the devs won't get confused.

Comment: @Shog9 Something just like this [happened on IPS](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1411/345) today.

Answer (score 11):

You've come across what I'd call rather strange behavior, but I'm not certain that it's necessarily a bug. I'm calling it Schrödinger's Revision <sup>™</sup>

It appears that you were trying to roll back to a previous body revision while preserving tag changes. However, since all you changed was the tags, that's the only post history record created.

Since it was identical to the current set of tags, nothing shows up in the revision history. Hence, it was a revision, but wasn't a revision, and seemingly isn't a revision yet it is. But hey, it wasn't caching!

We're looking at it. This is a rather strange edge case, we are examining it to see if changes need to be made, if only to be made more obvious.