# Link markdown in chat fails if the link contains a url

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, hyperlinks

The chat markdown parser fails to properly create a link when the link itself contains multiple "http://". Example

**Markdown:**

```
View older versions of [StackOverflow](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/)
```

**Expected result:**

> View older versions of [StackOverflow](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://stackoverflow.com/)

**[Actual result:](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29567786#29567786)**

> View older versions of [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)" rel="nofollow">StackOverflow

This bug only appears in the timeline, and when looking at the [history of a message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/29567786/history)

Outside the visual oddities of this bug, this bug also generates invalid html as a side effect of it.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/chat-markdown-do-not-parse-links-or-tags-with-an-asterisk-in-them